# How to Load Url For WebView In Another Fragment

Tags: android, url, for-loop, webview, fragment

I Want Replace The WebView Fragmnet With ActivityFragment When Click On A ExpandableListView Item .

This is My WebView Fragment :

```
 View mview;

 WebView view ;

 ProgressDialog mProgress ;

 @Override

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.siteview,container, false);

     Bundle bundle = getArguments();

       String url = bundle.getString("url");
         view = (WebView) mview.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

      WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


       view.loadUrl(url);

       view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
           }


       });

    return mview;
  }


}
```

And This Is My Fragment Activity OnChildclick of Expendabels List

```
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                Fragment siteview = new siteview();

               // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


                //setTitle(menutitles[position]);
            // Click Jadval's Child
            if (groupPosition == 2 & childPosition == 0){
                mNav.toggleRightDrawer();  

               // bundle.putString("url", customHtml1.toString());

               // siteview.setArguments(bundle);

                transaction.replace(R.id.fram, siteview);

                // Commit the transaction
            }
                else if (groupPosition == 2 & childPosition == 1 ){
                mNav.toggleRightDrawer();  

            }
            transaction.commit()    ;           

            return false;

        }
```

This Code Not Working .
Where is the problem? 
Please give me tips

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong you are looking for, when you click on any item in list view it has to open particular fragment. for that you need to work on position of list. and on that particular position set a particular fragment. 
some thing like

```
switch(position)
{
   case 0:
    case 1:
 }


    and fragment class should be like this


 public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
WebView wv;
public SearchFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, 
    false);

    wv=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_web);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
   }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```